# How should I deal with critical comment that may affect on my research path?

Tags: computer-science, editors, research-topic

A few days ago I posted a question on specific paper on RG. Another researcher says this is insulated paper that really shocked me because it is central to my research.

After I saw this comment I contact this person to get more explanation that may guide me but he didn't respond.

The paper name is "Multimodal Registration of Remotely Sensed Images Based on Jeffrey’s Divergence, 2016" and my interest is multimodal image registration, below you will find a screenshot for the discussion.
[image]

I post this question to get some advice from senior researchers that may pass through a situation.

*Update: How can Q1 journal accept to publish insulated work?*

Thanks

Comment: @Nat I read the word correctly but my worry come from this comment because I don't want to put effort on work no one accept to publish.

Comment: Was the "insulated work" comment really by *another researcher?* The comment reads as if it was made by the paper's author (or at least by the one to which you addressed the question). Can you clarify the situation?

Comment: Why would a Q1 journal not accept a paper because the author does not generally work on that field? They will just have a look and if its good accept it. To repeat what other people said: The paper itself is good, the author is telling you that he/she does not work on that topic, so they can not help you. The paper itself has absolutely not problem (at least none is shown in this interaction)

Comment: I think it would help if we knew what you think *"insulated"* means here.  It's not really clear what you are worried about.

Comment: *How can Q1 journal accept to publish insulated work?* Why shouldn't the journal accept it if it is good? There is **nothing bad at all** about an isolated work. It just means that the authors do not work on this topic any more.

Comment: @Angew the comment didn't post by the paper's author. Interestingly, the comment writer has 2 papers in multimodal image registration the latest one in 2009.

Comment: @VladimirF the commenter isn't the paper's author.

Comment: I have no idea what is meant by this question and I personally think the author of said paper would not be happy to have screenshots of online conversations with them be publicized in strange SE questions which are hard to understand...

Comment: @nagdawi: He didn't respond because he didn't want to give you his code. Contrary to their public opinions on whether *others* should release their code, researchers are not always happy to just send you a copy. What do they get in return? If the code is poorly written or if you find a bug, they may feel embarrassed—or you may be someone who might embarrass them. And if the code is good, they might want to retain the ability to use it for commercial advantage later. None of this should critically affect your research direction.

Comment: @Mehrdad There are other, far more innocuous explanations. If the screen shot is a threaded conversation, the OP has already gotten an answer, and they may feel they may not have more to contribute. Or they suspect the field has moved on, and may not have advice that they think is still relevant. Or they're busy, and don't feel like helping someone with a side project they've long since left behind.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

"Insulated" is a strange word to use there, but that reads for all the world like "This was a one-off project for me I don't really work on anymore".

Many academics end up having those. It doesn't mean anything about *your* research, and definitely isn't "shocking".

To respond to your edit, one-off or isolated projects aren't inherently better or worse science than any other project, so there's no reason a top tier journal wouldn't publish someone's side study. Indeed one of *my* best publications is from a one-off project.

Comment: I find your answer absolutely correct. But, still the author would have guided in getting some more information on the work for OP (which is of course a personal choice).

Comment: Probably "insulated" is a spell-corrected typo for "isolated".

Comment: @JeffE In Italian, the word *isolare* means both *to insulate* and *to isolate*.  (The same is true in other romance languages, too.)  So it could also just be a small translation mistake.

Comment: @fomite I update my question. I appreciate any more advices from you.

Comment: @nagdawi See the edit

Answer (score 11):

I suggest the reading 'isolated' --- he probably meant a one-off effort.

*Isola* is the Italian for island (from Latin *insula*). *Isolare* means *to isolate* and *to insulate* at the same time. The Italian writer may have had his/her wires crossed at that moment.

I ignore if there is an etymological connection between the notion of island and that of solitude/seclusion/isolation. As a matter of fact, small islands are sanctuaries for solitude, and Napoleon was confined to St Helena to stay in isolation.

Comment: Your answer sparked a chuckle from me.

Comment: You are right there is a connection: _insula_ is latin for _island_ and still valid Spanish. English _insulate_ does indeed come from that latin word. On the other hand, _isolate_ apparently comes through French and Italian, but still from the same word _insula_. It's easy for romance-based language speakers to mix the two. In English they have different meanings ( [ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=insulate%2C+isolate&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7) ).